# What is the difference between "subject" and "object" of study/research?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Let's say that I collected data on a person: his favourites, character, attributes, behaviour, etc. Was he the **subject** or **object** of my study/research?

Next, I collect data on an ethnic community: their culture. Is this ethnic community the **subject** or the **object** of my study/research?

Finally, I will collect data on a mountain (non-living): it's height, it's history, etc. Will this mountain be the **subject** or the **object** of my study/research?

I looked up the two words in an Oxford dictionary and I found similar meanings:

1. **Subject**:
   a person or thing that is being discussed, described, or dealt with.
   *"I've said all there is to be said on the subject"*
2. **Object**:
   a person or thing to which a specified action or feeling is directed.
   *"disease became the object of investigation"*

Comment: They are more or less interchangable, but *subject* is more common in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question. It's a strange shift of meanings, and it doesn't end with scientific research. "Subject" also means "a person ruled over by another, especially a monarch or state authority" ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/subject)), but since it is ruled over we can say it's actually an object.

I couldn't find any research on this point. But I figured out some arguments myself:

1. Use "subject" when you passively observe it. Use "object" when you actively affect it and change its behavior.

   Yes, an object is "a person or thing to which a specified action is directed". But just an observation is hardly counts as an action. If a person continues to act by his own will and you just register its behavior then he is still a subject. He continues to do it regardless of your presence and observation.

   The same argument applies to communities. And it can be extended to a mountain too. Until you perform some actions to change the natural order of things (e.g. you detonate explosions in order to observe an avalanche), it's still a subject.

   Sure, ideal passive observation is impossible (see e.g. [observer effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_effect_(physics))), But you should at least clarify your intentions.
2. Use "subject" for persons and high-developed animals. Or define "object" more precisely.

   "Object" has a negative connotation since you *objectivize* it. Yes, as a researcher you strive towards objectivity. But "object" sounds unethical. So, I'd use "subject" for persons and animals regardless of the distinction made in #1.

   On the other hand, generally you don't research a subject as the whole. In your example, you actually study a person's favorites, character, attributes and behavior. So you can say that favorites, character etc. are objects of your research. And then you don't need to talk about the subject at all.

[This answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/521063/54002) also proposes to use "agent" for a person taking an active role in an experiment.